# In C# where does the key words come from if "using system" is commented?

Tags: c#

For example, we know that "int" type in C# is nothing but a structure which is actually System.Int32. If that so, then if "using system;" is commented in a program, then int type should not be able to use. But still int type can be used. My question is, from where these types are coming from?

```
//using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main() {
         int x = 0;  // it still work, though int is under System namespace, why??
    }
}
```

Comment: The *int* type is certainly not a structure.  It is what got you on the wrong footing, the C# compiler has hard-coded knowledge of what Int32 looks like.  So much so that *int* is a keyword in the language.  And it doesn't have to be Int32 forever, a hundred years from now it may well be another type.

Comment: @HansPassant I got this info from msdn 
link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.int32.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Sure, that's what it looks like, the .NET Framework was written in C#.  Declaring the Int32 type in C# is a hopeless chicken-and-egg problem, the structure trick was a workaround for that.

Comment: @HansPassant The core semantics of `Int32` are baked into IL. `x + y` if `x` and `y` are `int`s is *very* different than if they were plain old C# types with a custom operator. C# in a sense just builds on top of the lower-level language. At least, I find it much more useful to think about it that way.

Comment: Not really, there's only one Opcodes.Add and it is used for several types.  But yes, like the C# compiler there's lots of hard-coded knowledge of Int32 in the jitter and the CLR.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Type aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx) like `int`, `string`, `object`, etc. are built into the language and do not require a `using` directive to be able to use, unlike `DateTime` for example.

However, if it helps you to think about it, you can consider `int` to be short for `global::System.Int32`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main() {
         int x = 0;
    }
}
```

Translates to

```
class Program
{
    static void Main() {
         global::System.Int32 x = 0;
    }
}
```

In fact, because the type aliases are keywords, you can't even re-define them as you might expect:

```
public class int { } // Compiler error: Identifier expected; 'int' is a keyword
```

If for some reason you wanted to do this, you'd have to escape the identifier like this:

```
public class @int { }

int x = 0;             // equivalent to global::System.Int32
@int y = new @int();   // equivalent to global::MyNamespace.@int
```

Comment: I think it is quite accurate to consider `int` a shorthand for `global::System.Int32`. Creating a type `@int` is irrelevant. But you can write `namespace System { public struct Int32 { } }` in your program. After that the `int` pre-defined keyword will refer to that struct. You will however get a warning if you still refer `mscorlib.dll` because that assemply also has a `System.Int32`. If you wanted to, you could compile without reference to `mscorlib.dll`, but you would need to hand-write really many "pre-defined" types!

Comment: Just tested it, and my memory was not exact, for the `System.Int32` of `mscorlib.dll` is preferred over the `System.Int32` in my project. But I can [compile without reference to `mscorlib.dll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa13yay7.aspx) as I mentioned, and then I will have to write a hell lot of "pre-defined" types by hand, including the `System.Int32`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Are you saying that you can make `int x = 0` compile to something other than `ldc.i4.1;stloc.0`, or just that you can just make `typeof(System.Int32)` return a different type than the one defined in mscorlib.dll?

Comment: Not quite sure. I am really sure I can make `int.Parse("");` call a strange method I write, though. It is clear that a lot of assumptions about what `int` is are built into the compiler. The `struct Int32` itself is not used much, in the IL created. I am sure Hans Passant or someone will have more to say about that. Edit: As I remember it, the struct `Int32` contains an instance field of type `int`. Normally that would be impossible for a struct (an infinite cycle in the struct lay-out). Clearly there's a lot of magic here.